# .htaccess url rewrite not passing parameter - could there be apache settings somewhere that is preventing this?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay, so this problem has completely stumped me and the other devs I work with. Here is the rundown:

I have a local dev environment setup with Mac Apache2 pointed at /Users/myusername/Sites/

Within /Sites I have two folders, /site-1 and /site-2, both of which have virtual hosts pointed at them site-1.dev & site-2.dev. Both site-1 and site-2 are running local installs of PerchCMS.

Within /site-2 I have an .htaccess file which I am trying to set up a URL rewrite that takes the URL /detail/slug-here and translates it into /detail.php?s=slug-here

I have tried the following rewrites (at the suggestion of PerchCMS support) and both have failed to pass the s param:

```
RewriteRule ^detail/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detail.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^site-2/detail/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /site-2/detail.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Additional info:

1. Yes mod_rewrite is enabled in apache... in the same .htaccess file it totally works if I do a simple rewrite like this...

   ```
   RewriteRule dangerzone.html index.php
   ```
2. One odd behavior that I've noticed is that if I remove everything from .htaccess I can still pull up detail.php by pointing my browser at /detail/test-item-1...(yes I have restarted my server) so its behaving as if there is still some sort of rewrite in place and loading detail.php sans param just as it continues to do with the rewrite in place - is this a clue that there is something off somewhere else in my server config? Note, `RewriteRule dangerzone.html index.php` does NOT work once it is removed from .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this code in your site root .htaccess (inside `/site-2/`):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^detail/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)/?$ detail.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Important is to turn off `MultiViews` options here. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted because I did what you said and it totally worked! Thank you @anubhava

EDIT: I tried to give you an upvote but I don't have the rep :(